# Changing batch to shell

Tags: shell

This is my first question, and I've finally resorted to asking as my hours of googles haven't returned anything good. Would it be possible to convert this batch script to a Linux shell?

```
@echo off
cd ../bin
color 0a
Title DavidScape 508
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin\java.exe" DavidScape/Server 43594
pause
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how?

Comment: What is it that have you tried?

Comment: I did many searches about how to convert them. I've just been really confused, and Wine has been giving me errors as well. I tried changing the cd and echo to #/bin/sh, but overall I've been very stuck

Answer (score 2):

Something close would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ../bin
echo -ne "\033[40;1;32m"
java DavidScape/Server 43594
read
```

Comment: Literal translation! Nice.. :)

Comment: Using literal ANSI color codes is not a best practice -- not all terminals support ANSI; using `tput` will provide a color code only if one is available for the current terminal.

Comment: I'd say the number of systems not having `tput` is greater then the terminals where such a sequence would cause a problem. not all system have ncurses.